# Is there any better way to concurrently call REST API in spring client implementation?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm implementing one service which is internally calling some third party rest API to get the data and process over it. API call can be N number of times based on different user input data, so it can call the API 100 times or 10000 times as well and each API call takes 1-2 seconds on an average that will increase the total time for overall process.

I want to understand if there's any best way to handle such problem smoothly?
I was planning for concurrent API call about 100 times or 1000 times(thread running using @async spring boot method) but again this number of threads execution speed will depend on the system it is running on.

Your reply will be great help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the bottleneck is the response time of the third party api, you'll always run into time problems. It's not only the execution of the thread, you'll have to provide a thread pool and I guess the number of threads you mention maybe scaled on multiple service replicas will always cause problems. Can't you split your logik? Maybe have a look at the restTemplate specification to call another service.

Comment: First you have to develop a minimal working solution and collect metrics. This will allow you to see where the bottleneck is and how you can optimize the performance. This to me looks like something you cannot scale vertically and you need to scale it horizontally by throwing more nodes/clusters/server instance to do the computation.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to reactor project. It requires some effort if you want to be efficient with it, but the code would be pretty simple and if you use Spring 5/Boot 2 then you could take advantage of NIO Spring Web Client. Otherwise it will be similar to what you've suggested - run concurrently X API calls

Comment: Any idea, at one time how many thread it can run concurrently at maximum to avoid other system imapct?

Comment: There's no good answer. You have to test it, because it depends on server host (machine), software, if it has rate limiting etc.